# adding a border around SceneKit node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

i am trying to highlight a selected node in SceneKit with a tap gesture. Unfortunately, I have not been able to accomplish it. The best thing I could do was to change the material when the node is tapped.

```
let material = key.geometry!.firstMaterial!
material.emission.contents = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Can someone suggest a way I can go about to just add a border or outline around the object instead of changing the color of the entire node?

Comment: You mean an `SKSpriteNode` right? Not a `SKNode`.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, i am using scene kit .. scnnode

Answer (score 8):

Based on @Karl Sigiscar answer and another answer here in SO I came up with this:

```swift
func createLineNode(fromPos origin: SCNVector3, toPos destination: SCNVector3, color: UIColor) -> SCNNode {
    let line = lineFrom(vector: origin, toVector: destination)
    let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: line)
    let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = color
    line.materials = [planeMaterial]

    return lineNode
}

func lineFrom(vector vector1: SCNVector3, toVector vector2: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {
    let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]

    let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2])
    let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .line)

    return SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
}


func highlightNode(_ node: SCNNode) {
    let (min, max) = node.boundingBox
    let zCoord = node.position.z
    let topLeft = SCNVector3Make(min.x, max.y, zCoord)
    let bottomLeft = SCNVector3Make(min.x, min.y, zCoord)
    let topRight = SCNVector3Make(max.x, max.y, zCoord)
    let bottomRight = SCNVector3Make(max.x, min.y, zCoord)


    let bottomSide = createLineNode(fromPos: bottomLeft, toPos: bottomRight, color: .yellow)
    let leftSide = createLineNode(fromPos: bottomLeft, toPos: topLeft, color: .yellow)
    let rightSide = createLineNode(fromPos: bottomRight, toPos: topRight, color: .yellow)
    let topSide = createLineNode(fromPos: topLeft, toPos: topRight, color: .yellow)

    [bottomSide, leftSide, rightSide, topSide].forEach {
        $0.name = kHighlightingNode // Whatever name you want so you can unhighlight later if needed
        node.addChildNode($0)
    }
}

func unhighlightNode(_ node: SCNNode) {
    let highlightningNodes = node.childNodes { (child, stop) -> Bool in
        child.name == kHighlightingNode
    }
    highlightningNodes.forEach {
        $0.removeFromParentNode()
    }
}
```

Comment: the line is too thin, is it possible to make line look more thick?

Comment: Implemented this, but no line is visible.... The nodes were added, but not visible....

Answer (score 3):

SCNNode conforms to the SCNBoundingVolume Protocol.

This protocol defines the [getBoundingBoxMin:max:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNBoundingVolume_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNBoundingVolume/getBoundingBoxMin:max:) method.

Use this to get the minimum and maximum coordinates of the bounding box of the geometry attached to the node.

Then use the SceneKit primitive type [SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scngeometryprimitivetype/scngeometryprimitivetypeline) to draw the lines of the bounding box. Check SCNGeometryElement.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code on how to do this? Even i am looking for the same solution

Answer (score -3):

If your node is a primitive shape you can set a `UIImage` as the `diffuse`. The image will get stretched out to cover your node. If you use an image with a border on it, this will translate to creating a border on your node.

```
planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "blueSquareOutline.png")
```

[image: Example border image]